# Iterate boolean comparison over two DataFrames?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have created two DF sets, one with a generic number list and another with a specific number list. I want to iterate over the first list and compare it to the second list; if GenericList[X] is equal to any number in SpecificNumber list, I want a return of True and if not, False.

I have tried to utilize a if loop, something similar to for ( num <- List ) print (list) if .....

```scala
scala> val genericList = List(5,6,7,8,9,10)
scala> val df = genericList.toDF
scala> val specificList = List(5,-3,8)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with **`.exists`** and **`.contains`** functions to check the number.

```
scala> val genericList = List(5,6,7,8,9,10)
scala> val specificList = List(5,-3,8)
scala> genericList.exists(specificList.contains)
res1: Boolean = true
```

***`In Dataframe API:`***

```
scala> val genericList = List(5,6,7,8,9,10)
scala> val df = genericList.toDF
scala> val specificList = List(5,-3,8)
scala> df.withColumn("check",'value.isin(specificList:_*)).show()
+-----+-----+
|value|check|
+-----+-----+
|    5| true|
|    6|false|
|    7|false|
|    8| true|
|    9|false|
|   10|false|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: This is incredibly helpful!! Thank you!

Comment: @y_291 Then you probably want to accept the answer.